# Blew away my php-fpm, trying to get anew

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, php

I was doing a

> brew install php56

on my Mac OS 10.9.5 (which came with php5.3 preinstalled). While rooting out the old install, I managed to

> sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/php-fpm

Of course, my php-fpm command is now not found, even after the install finishes. Thus, foreman dies.

**Where can I go to get a new php-fpm**, or how can I link the ones that come with brew's php56 lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) and a OS X install .dmg to restore your php-fpm, or borrow it from a friend's computer.

In general it's dangerous to remove the versions of tools that OS X installs for you.